# How to change tk.Label's content after assigning?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm writing a simple to-do list program with Tkinter and I've ran in a problem: the "Add task" button doesn't do anything! Please tell me what's wrong with my program and how to fix it. Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

tasks = ["Enter a new task...", "Enter a new task...", "Enter a new task..."]

window = tk.Tk()
title = tk.Label(text="To-Do List")
t0 = tk.Label(text=tasks[0])
t1 = tk.Label(text=tasks[1])
t2 = tk.Label(text=tasks[2])

def addTask():
    count = 0
    tasks[count] = newTask.get()
    count += 1
    if count == 3:
        count = 0

newTask = tk.Entry()
newTaskButton = tk.Button(text="Add task", command=addTask())

t0.pack()
t1.pack()
t2.pack()
newTask.pack()
newTaskButton.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: To answer your titular question: To change the text of an existing `Label`, call its [`config()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#setting-options) method: i.e. `t1.config(text='new content')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
command=addTask()
```

should be

```
command=addTask
```

This is because the button receives the address or id of the function to call and does the call inside the button process. `addTask()` calls the `addTask` function directly and will not work.